# Fancybox not displaying PDF but will download it

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

I am using [FancyBox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display PDF files. When accessing the file directly through the file system, it works perfectly.

However, due to file restrictions we have, I am unable to do this through the file system directly. I have created an endpoint that returns a `FileResult` through ASP.NET API but as a result, the FancyBox is downloading the file instead of showing it. The return `File` object has a content type of `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf`

I'm not sure of the best approach to handle this and the documentation is sparse.

The link looks like

```
<a role="button" data-document-id="@(document.id)" data-fancybox href="~/api/DownloadDocument?documentID=@document.Id&type=@(document.extension)" class="btn btn-success">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than returning a `FileResult` object, return the file in a stream (`FileStreamResult`). This will produce the same behaviour as referencing the file path directly and allow it to be rendered in `FancyBox` as opposed to immediately downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Fancybox. It just creates iframe element and points source to your file. So, if you can simply embed your PDF in your HTML document using `<iframe>` element, then it will also work in Fancybox. Fancybox is not parsing and rendering your file, you can use https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ for that.

Comment: FancyBox is already working for images using the same method. As I said earlier as well, it's working perfectly when directly referencing the file location. I would more like to know how to restore this functionality when calling the file from an API endpoint.

Comment: Also looking at it, it also appears that FancyBox is already putting  it in an iFrame?

Comment: Putting what? Also, if you have any questions about .NET, then ask about it and don't involve Fancybox there.

Comment: Did you try creating element like this? `<iframe src="~/api/DownloadDocument?documentID=@document.Id&type=@(document.extension)"></iframe>`? Did it work?

Comment: I appreciate the help but the solution was to stream the data as opposed to returning a `FileResult`. I mentioned FancyBox because that was the tool I was trying to use to display the PDF documents. I was also confused as to why it would work in FancyBox when reference a direct path to the file as opposed to the API that returns a file. A bulk of my question was referencing .NET.